# Webview for any external links refering to its domain?

Tags: java, android, dns, android-webview, hyperlink

Do you know that when you click in a any link the system ask you with which browser/application you want open it? Starting from this concept, is it possible do it in my webview? For example when the domain is `www.stackoverflow.com` it ask me if i want open the link with my webview (created for stackoverflow links only)?. I don't know if i'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following tags under the `<activity>` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

The system includes your app in the list when a user clicks on a StackOverflow link.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.stackoverflow.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

**Updated**

You can use `getIntent()` inside your `Activity` to get the parameters (URL). Add the following lines in `onCreate` method of your `Activity`.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String url = intent.getData().toString();
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: How can i use `getIntent()`? Actually i use `webview.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: I tried `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
       Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(i);` . When i open the application it ask me with which application i want open it (It's strange, because it must open as default that link with that application). And when i try to click  a link send my friend via mail (simply www.stackoverflow.com) it ask me only open with the browsers not with application

Comment: Your app needs to receive the intent instead of sending out. `startActivity` is used to open another activity (app) to show the URL. That is not what you intend to do, right? You want to receive the URL when some other app wants to open some StackOverflow URL.

Comment: exactly..so what you suggest?

Comment: As I described in my answer post, Add `<intent-filter>` in your AndroidManifest.xml, and call getIntent() in your `onCreate` method to receive a URL from some other app.